# Sending HTTPPost in Android

Tags: android, http-post

I am new to android development. What I am trying to do is send some data on a server. i.e. the HTTPPOst.

For example I want to send an image or send an XML in the HTTP Post's Body....
Can some body give me sample code or project.

Comment: This has been answered on SO numerous times!

Comment: @Raunak if u know that it has been answered previously then its better if u post the link of these questions

Comment: Fair Point. As you can see, the answer is back from '11 and at that point in time, I was still learning how to be a valuable citizen! :)